# Are "academic society" and "industrial society" correct?

Tags: idioms, terminology

I'm writing a Personal Statement and I need to say something like "this research topic is hot in both *academic society* and *industrial society*". Are these phrases correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I might say, "[…] in academia and in industry […]."

Answer (score 8):

Possibly using "...in both academic and industrial circles" would be better, but it may depend on the wider context of the statement.

Instead of 'circles' you could also use 'groups.'

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is `(with)in the academic community`. Not sure if you can write `industrial community` though.